# Bash recognizes function argument as a program

Tags: bash, bashrc, bash-alias

I'm pretty new to the syntax of bash and I have a piece of code in my '.bash_aliases' file. It either gets an integer as an argument or the letter 'c', when it gets an integer, it puts that integer in a environment variable, which can be used by webservers as a port. When it gets the letter 'c' as it's input, it clears the variable.

When I try to run my command with an integer I get the error

```bash
main@linuxWSL:~$ serverp 2000
-bash: [: missing `]'
2000: command not found
```

and when I try it with the letter 'c' I get

```bash
main@linuxWSL:~$ serverp c
-bash: [: missing `]'
c: command not found
```

This is my bash code:

```bash
serverp () {
  if [ "$1" = "clear" || "$1" = "c" ]
  then
    unset PORT
    echo -e "\e$CLEAR$GREEN""mWebServer port has been reset!""$CLEAN"
    return 0
  fi

  export PORT="$1"
}
```

Can someone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` is not a keyword in Bash that would make the shell parser interpret the rest of the command line differently. `[` is a command like `cat` or `echo`. `[` (like `echo`) is a builtin in Bash, but this only means it can be run without spawning an additional process, it still behaves like a command.

And to be clear: `[ … ]` is not a part of `if … then …` syntax. `if` just tests the exit status of some code: `if true; then …` is valid, `if sleep 5; then …` is valid, similarly `if [ … ]; then …` is valid (if the `[ … ]` part is itself a valid command).

There is probably a `[` executable in your system. Try `type -a [`. Compare to `type -a [[`. Contrary to `[`, `[[` is a keyword in Bash and it does make the parser treat things between `[[` and `]]` specially.

`[` is not a keyword. Properly written `[ … ]` is a command where `]` is just the last argument. `[` requires `]` as the last argument, otherwise it refuses to work. This is only to make `[ … ]` stand out as a block, as if it was some special syntax; but it's not a special syntax.

Your `[ "$1" = "clear" || "$1" = "c" ]` is interpreted by the shell as `[ "$1" = "clear"` and `"$1" = "c" ]` connected with `||`. So there are two commands. The first command is `[ "$1" = "clear"`, the `[` gets executed, it doesn't get `]` as the last argument, it complains and exits with a non-zero exit status. Because of the non-zero status and because of `||`, the shell tries to run the second command which starts with whatever `"$1"` expands to. This way the first argument to your script is interpreted as an executable to run.

Fix your `[ … || … ]` like this:

```
[ "$1" = "clear" ] || [ "$1" = "c" ]
```

This snippet consists of two *valid* `[` commands. It should do what you want.

Note `[[ "$1" = "clear" || "$1" = "c" ]]` is a working piece of code while `[ "$1" = "clear" || "$1" = "c" ]` is not. This is because `[[` is not a command. It's a keyword and it makes the shell parser treat everything up to `]]` specially; this includes the `||`. There are other [differences between `[[` and `[`](https://superuser.com/a/1708896/432690), don't interchange them blindly.

The `[` builtin in Bash supports `-o` for *or* (and `-a` for *and*), so this will also work:

```
[ "$1" = "clear" -o "$1" = "c" ]
```

It is your code where `||` (special to the shell) was replaced by `-o` (not special to the shell). You should avoid `-o` though. From [this article](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.22.24foo.22_.3D_bar_.26.26_.22.24bar.22_.3D_foo_.5D):

> The binary `-a` and `-o` […] are XSI extensions to the POSIX standard. All are marked as obsolescent in POSIX-2008. They should not be used in new code. One of the practical problems with `[ A = B -a C = D ]` (or `-o`) is that POSIX does not specify the results of a `test` or `[` command with more than 4 arguments. It probably works in most shells, but you can't count on it. If you have to write for POSIX shells, then you should use two `test` or `[` commands separated by a `&&` operator instead.

Note the article elaborates on `-a`, so "a `&&` operator instead". In your case it's `-o` and `||` respectively. Two tests separated by a `||` operator is exactly our solution.

Comment: Your solution was very helpful, thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

It's `if [ "$1" = "clear" ] || [ "$1" = "c" ]`.