# Check if folder contains files with extensions and write directories into categories

Tags: linux, bash

I have around 3k + folders, and they can have two types of files, a single spring file and a pair of fastq.gz files. I want to scan the folders and know if both or either of the file extension is present in the directory -

1. Contain a pair of fastq.gz and spring file
2. One fastq.gz file and spring file
3. A single spring file
4. A pair of fastq.gz files
5. Single fastq.gz file

I used `[ /path/to/dir/*fastq.gz ]` but I'm getting `unary operator expected` error, and using `[[ ]]` doesn't seem to be testing things correctly.

The actual script I used is -

```
check_dir () {
in="$1"
echo "$in Checking for spring"
[ "$in"/*spring -f ] && echo "$in"
}
export -f check_dir
```

I'm using bash, any help with logic will be appreciated

Comment: try `[ -f "$in"/*spring ]` instead of  `[ "$in"/*spring -f ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unary operator expected` is because `[` and `*` (in your `*fastq.gz`) work independently.

`[` is not shell syntax. `[` is a regular command (a builtin in Bash, but still a command) and `]` is its last *argument*, a mandatory one. Anything in between is an argument too.

The shell expands `/path/to/dir/*fastq.gz` to one or more words before it calls `[`. `[` will see these words plus the mandatory `]` as arguments. Depending on the number of arguments and what they are, `[` expects zero or more argument(s) to be operators (like `-f`).

Your `[ /path/to/dir/*fastq.gz ]` will be valid if `/path/to/dir/*fastq.gz` expands to a single argument (note "will be valid" is not equivalent to "will do what you want"). This includes cases where `*` matches nothing; traditionally (and by default in Bash) if there is no match then `/path/to/dir/*fastq.gz` will be processed as-is. It may happen `/path/to/dir/*fastq.gz` expands to multiple words, none of them will look like an operator `[` understands. The error you got is most likely from a case where the pattern expanded to two words.

Later you used `[ "$in"/*spring -f ]`. This is even worse, because you probably wanted something like `[ -f some/path ]` where `-f` is *before* the path to test. Still `[ -f "$in"/*spring ]` is not a robust fix because `"$in"/*spring` *in general* may expand to multiple arguments and `[` will not stand them. You wrote there is at most one `*spring` file per directory, so *in your case* code like this may kinda work; it's still poor code though.

With `[`, do not use wildcards like `*` that may expand to multiple words; this will fail immediately or soon. [`[[` is different under the hood](https://superuser.com/a/1708896/432690) but it's not good for your purpose either.

You want to know how many files a pattern like `/path/to/dir/*fastq.gz` matches. The right way to do it is to assign the result of the expansion to an array. Portably there's only one array: the array of arguments of the shell script (or the shell function); and you need extra code to detect a case of zero matches (that still generates one word: the unexpanded pattern string). Your question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), so I will use a named array and few other non-portable functionalities:

```bash
# non-portable code, works in Bash
check_dir () (
   dir="${1-.}"
   dir="${dir%/}/"
   [ -d "$dir" ] || { echo "Not a directory." >&2; return 1; }
   shopt -s nullglob
   files=( "$dir"/*fastq.gz )
   nf="${#files[@]}"
   files=( "$dir"/*spring )
   ns="${#files[@]}"
   printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$nf" "$ns" "$dir"
)
```

Usage: `check_dir path/to/dir` or `check_dir` (the default path is `.`). The function will print the number of `*fastq.gz` files, a tab, the number of `*spring` files, a tab, finally the examined path (printed with a trailing `/`).

Now you can analyze a directory tree (the below function requires the above function to be defined):

```bash
# non-portable code, works in Bash
check_dirs () (
   dir="${1-.}"
   dir="${dir%/}/"
   [ -d "$dir" ] || { echo "Not a directory." >&2; return 1; }
   shopt -s nullglob globstar
   for d in "$dir"**/; do
      check_dir "$d"
   done
)
```

Usage: `check_dirs path/to/dir` or `check_dirs` (the default path is `.`).

Notes:

- For a large directory tree `check_dirs` may seem to initially stall. This is because `for d in "$dir"**/` needs to be fully expanded before `check_dir` is ever called and prints anything.
- The functions are deliberately defined as subshells (`check_dir () (` as opposed to `check_dir () {`), so shell options (`shopt`) and all variables are local.
- If you want `check_dir` to count hidden files, you need `dotglob` in this function (i.e. `shopt -s nullglob dotglob`).
- If you want `check_dirs` to descend to hidden directories, you need `dotglob` in this function (i.e. `shopt -s nullglob globstar dotglob`).
- Unless the names of your directories contain newline characters, the output from `check_dir` or `check_dirs` is easily parsable with standard tools. Useful commands: `sort -n`, `grep $'^2\t1\t'`, `cut -f 3-`.

  E.g. to find directories under `./` with exactly one `*fastq.gz` file and exactly zero `*spring` files:

  ```
  check_dirs | grep $'^1\t0\t' | cut -f 3-
  ```