# How to convert code from test format to if fi format?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have code that opens a bash file in a terminal for entering the sudo password:

```
test "$IN_TERM" || {
    export IN_TERM=1
    konsole -e "$0"
    exit 0
} && true
```

I need to convert it to a form with `if fi` tags. I tried this option, but then an infinite number of terminals open:

```
if [[ -n $IN_TERM ]]; then  
    export IN_TERM=1  
    else  
    konsole -e "$0"  
    exit 0
fi
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most direct way to convert your code is:

```
if ! test "$IN_TERM"; then
    export IN_TERM=1
    konsole -e "$0"
    exit 0
fi
```

You can then rewrite it as

```
if ! [[ "$IN_TERM" ]]; then
    export IN_TERM=1
    konsole -e "$0"
    exit 0
fi
```

or

```
if [[ ! "$IN_TERM" ]]; then
    export IN_TERM=1
    konsole -e "$0"
    exit 0
fi
```

or

```
if [[ -z "$IN_TERM" ]]; then
    export IN_TERM=1
    konsole -e "$0"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: The thing is that I'm trying to get rid of `test` completely in code. I need to do something with `if [[ -n $IN_TERM ]]; then ...`

Comment: @moninah What’s the point exactly? At least with `bash`, `test` is a shell buil-in, just like `[[`. Anyway, I just added a few rewrites, with `[[` instead of `test`.

Comment: @moninah "I'm trying to get rid of `test` completely in code" – `test …` is *exactly equivalent* to `[ … ]`. [`[[` is somewhat different](https://superuser.com/a/1708896/432690). Any of the three can be used after `if` or without `if`. So what is the point?

Comment: @moninah If you just need to get rid of the `test` command, you might also simply rewrite your initial code as `[[ -n $IN_TERM ]] || { … } && true`. BTW, the `&& true` part looks useless.

Comment: @user2233709 Technically in Bash `[[` is not a builtin, it's a keyword and this fact has consequences. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1708896/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Just read that, thanks for the pointer. I was messing up with `[` and `[[`.

Comment: @user2233709 Thank you! Works great! As for why I want to get rid of the `test` in the code. Since I prefer to use opening and closing tags in my code, I find this more convenient for code readability. And the word `test` itself is associated with testing something.